# allowfullscreen not working with google chrome in html5 embedded youtube player

Tags: html, google-chrome, youtube

I have a problem with the embedded youtube html5 player. 
The button to display the video in full screen does not appear on Google Chrome. But it appears correctly on Firefox.

Here is the code you can test:

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/OIDnYMODZAQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

http://jsfiddle.net/barbuslex/3WBGP/

Can someone help me make it work on Google Chrome?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry it was just the "allowfullscreen" parameter which missing in iframe tag.

It solved !

Answer (score 1):

JS Fiddle disables allowing full screen inside its iFrames. This hides the button in the YouTube widget. If you open the link in a new tab outside of JS fiddle it will show the "full screen" button.

Comment: Oh ok bad exemple ^^ But in my website it doesn't work... Any idea ? http://forum.virtualdjing.com/topic-6085-video-medley-des-disney-a-la-voix-page-1.html